# How can i inner join two tables based on their ID?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am trying to create a task manager where projects have tasks .

But i'm having difficulty in displaying both project.project ( name ) and tasks.taks ( name of task ) .

My tables have the below fields :

```
project (project_id (PK) , project (name of project)
```

tasks( id, task(name of task) , project_id(Foreign key to PK).

I have tried

```
$sql="
SELECT project.project
     , tasks.task
     , tasks.description
     , tasks.Priority
     , tasks.Due 
  FROM project 
  JOIN tasks 
    on project.project_id = tasks.project_id 
 WHERE project_id='{$_GET['project_id']}'
";
```

but something seems to be wrong.

Thank you

Comment: What seems to be wrong?  Is it complaining that column `project_id` is ambiguous?

Comment: @RobertPrice the query doesnt work.(mysqli_query) prints FALSE

Comment: I'd guess you need to say which of the two project IDs you mean for the final WHERE, even though they're equivalent, i.e. `WHERE project.project_id = '...'`. Do you really not get an error message for this? Can you 'get last error' from the mysqli API? Try [`$mysqli->error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) or `mysqli_error($mysqli)`.

Comment: update where project_id='...' clause with where project.project_id='...' your query.

Comment: "something seems to be wrong" tells us nothing. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK.

Answer (score 1):

Although you havent stated any error (which would help getting your question answered very quickly) Your statment is ambigious.

```
$sql="
SELECT project.project
     , tasks.task
     , tasks.description
     , tasks.Priority
     , tasks.Due 
  FROM project 
  JOIN tasks 
    on project.project_id = tasks.project_id 
 WHERE project_id='{$_GET['project_id']}'
";
```

You have a `project_id` field in both your `project` table and your `tasks` table. Without specifying which one you are using the WHERE clause on, it will not work.

```
$sql="
SELECT project.project
     , tasks.task
     , tasks.description
     , tasks.Priority
     , tasks.Due 
  FROM project 
  JOIN tasks 
    on project.project_id = tasks.project_id 
 WHERE project.project_id='{$_GET['project_id']}'
";
```

Also please make sure that your $_GET['project_id'] is sanitized and prepared properly.

Comment: Of course, as long as it's prepared properly, we needn't worry about sanitization :-)